# Cshell commands

Tags: shell, tcsh

When I receive lines one by one, why do programmers sometimes write:

```
set line = ($<)
set line = ($line)
```

What exactly do those rows mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a csh overview here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh

I appreciate you may not use Linux but I always found O'Reilly's Linux in a Nutshell book great for shell scripting.

To specifically address your questions (from the post above so I could be wrong!)

- $< : get next line from stdin
- ($line) : will execute the contents of $line in a subshell

Of course, like all things with Csh - you should probably just use Bash and live happier :)

Dan

Answer (score 0):

```
set line = ($<)
```

This reads a line of input from stdin and then splits it into an array, separating words by white-space, so that `$line[1]` is the first word, `$line[2]` is the second word and so on.

```
set line = ($line)
```

This does the same as above, but where $line might have been a single word, it will become an array of words. i.e.:

```
set line = ($<)
```

is the same as:

```
set line = "$<"
set line = ($line)
```